# fann2 for Python - get network weights

Tags: python, neural-network, fann

I am using fann2 (the Python binding for the FANN library) to train neural networks. I have trouble getting the weights of the network and the bias terms. I can see that the neural_net object has the following 2 methods:

get_connection_array

get_bias_array

Both methods require arguments, and I can't figure out what they should be (I can't find any documentation for these methods in Python). Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The python module is just a thin wrapper around th C++ code.  Looks like this:

```
void get_bias_array(helper_array<unsigned int>* ARGOUT)
```

The argument is an array that the data gets copied into. I'm not sure what this is in python; I think you can pass in a new helper array and this call will allocate storage and copy the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex. That makes sense. I tried passing an array of the right size to "get_bias_array", but the program crashes. Do you know what is the right way of, say, passing an array of 3 unsigned int to the C++ function?

Comment: @Dom I'm sorry, I don’t know how to pass the right kind of array that fann expects from python. What you want to pass is the python wrapper is for helper_array, which is not necessarily either a python array or numpy array. However it seems that is what fann2 uses everywhere, so if you pass in a helper_array somewhere else you can use the same way here. The array can be empty, it will get allocated storage in the call.